# Validating form information with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm trying to validate user information on our registration form. I'm relatively new to JQuery so im having troubles getting the script to actually run and check the information. Right now im just testing to see if the Email Address field is empty. Once i can check for that i should be able to handle generating the rest of the error checking.

This is our **registration.html** file

```
 <html>
<head><title>Registration Form: jQuery</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/my_script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="myForm"  method="POST">
        Email Address: <input type="text" id="email"/><br />
        Password: <input type="password" id="pass"/><br />
        First Name: <input type="text" id="fName"/><br />
        Last Name: <input type="text" id="lName"/><br />
        <button id="submit">register</button>
    </form>

    <div id="ack"></div>

    <script src="registration.js"></script>

</body>
```

And this is the **registration.js** file I've been working on

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit").click(function(){
    if($("#email").val() = "")
    {
        alert("Email Address must not be empty.");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Success");
    }

}); 
});
```

Any help would be appreciated. If it matters, we have been using Adobe PhoneGap Build to generate a mobile version of our site and I believe we used JQuery to connect to our database. Thanks!

***EDIT*** Its fixed!It was a combination of my If statement being incorrect and not properly linking to the JQuery library. The console option of chrome helped greatly. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

You are simply missing one character to get this to work.

**[Here is a Fiddle to show it working](http://jsfiddle.net/enigmarm/B6et4/)**

```
//incorrect
if($("#email").val() = "")

//correct
if($("#email").val() == "")
```

Essentially you were trying to assign an empty string to the `val()` of your selector.

The difference between `=` and `==` and `===` is a common thing to trip up people that are newer to JavaScript.

```
=   //assignment operator (x = 10)
==  //comparison operator - just checks value 
    // ('1' == 1) is true
=== //comparison operator - checks type & value
    // ('1' === 1) is false
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that! When i hit the register button though there is still no alert. Am i linking to my registration.js wrong?

Comment: It should work as long as `registration.html` and `registration.js` are within the same folder.

Comment: Try debugging things to see if it's even getting into your event listener. `$("#submit").click(function(){ console.log("this is working") ....`
`console.log()` will then display a message for you within the browser's console. If you're new to javascript, then the console will become your best friend for debugging.

Comment: Awesome!! I didnt know i could access a console through chrome. It seems im not referencing the JQuery library correctly so its not understanding any of the JQuery. Ill post back after i fix that.

Comment: Glad it worked out. If everything worked out, go ahead and select one of the answers as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Your If statement is wrong.
Should be this:

```
if($("#email").val() == "") { 
   alert("Empty email!"); 
} else { 
  alert($("#email").val()); 
}
```

If you want to check all fields in one statement you can do this:

```
if($("#field1").val() == "" || $("#field2").val() == "") {
    alert("Empty fields in form!")
} else {
    alert("Sucess!");
}
```

Small example: http://jsfiddle.net/VGgvm/